# Can the day pass on the Toronto subway be swiped?

Tags: public-transport, tickets, toronto

I have only bought weekly passes and I'm trying figure out a budget. Then I realized, if I'm going to buy a TTC day pass it would be useful to know if one can swipe through the turnstiles, because otherwise I would be stuck in long lines (especially in rush hour) if I must show the pass to the guy in the booth only, without having the swiping option.  That is time wasted.

Anybody know if you can swipe a day pass?

Comment: You cannot swipe a day pass, however, I've seen plenty of people with day passes jump the queue of people who are queueing up to pay, and this seems to be generally accepted.  Therefore, it will not delay you much.

Comment: @gerrit: I find just trying to buy tickets hell-ish because people just bump into you ruthlessly...I remember Queen station being one place I never want to stop to buy tickets. :-)  I think the weekly pass is worth the extra $ just to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ones I've seen work on a scratch-off method and [apparently lack a magnetic stripe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toronto_Transit_Commission_fares#Passes), so I think you'd be lining up to show it to the guy in the booth.

> Day Passes are printed on card paper; Weekly Passes and Metropasses have a magnetic strip for automatic turnstiles and so, like tokens, work at all subway/RT station entrances whether staffed or not. On surface vehicles, the pass is simply shown to the driver.

[image: Photo credit: Kiran Jheeta(@lala_coconuts)]

Comment: I live in Toronto, and I can confirm this is how day passes work.

Comment: Thank you!  This helps a lot! They don't mention this stuff on the TTC site.